# Securing REST api in spring boot using only OTP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session, jwt

I am trying to secure Spring boot REST apis that only need the user to enter a valid OTP (which I am already validating), I have no problem implementing this using sessions/cookies/JWTs but I need to use the simplest implementation that is supported by Spring boot to give the user a token or to know him in some way so that he will access the secured REST APIs.

I could create the Jwt & send it to the user, but Authenticating this across every API seems too much by making a filter & using it on every secured API

This is (compared with using something like [this reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/guides/html5/helloworld-boot.html#securing-the-application)) where we can see that Spring security already provides simple & global protection for the APIs but depends on authentication using username & password.

I don't want to recreate the wheel as in security I believe it is best to use standard libraries to avoid any issues.

What is the best practice for the scenario above as I was overwhelmed from the different approaches that I saw & I don't know what is the best?

1- Validating the Jwts in a central place for secured APIs?

2- Creating session for the user (without using Redis or DB) but only keeping it in Application server?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I already found that implementation but I was asking if there is some standard library to enforce using Jwts in Spring/Spring boot